# How to register global Vue components in Storybook?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, storybook

Is there a way to register global Vue components in Storybook so it is compatible with globally registered Vue components in Vue-CLI?

Answer (score 10):

You just need to add a few lines to `.storybook/preview.js` file.

**Vue.js 3**

```
import {app} from '@storybook/vue3';

app.component('router-link', MockRouterLink);
```

**Vue.js 2**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.component('router-link', MockRouterLink);
```

But I haven't tested the latter one because I only use Storybook with Vue.js 3 apps.

Comment: thankyou thankyou thankyou! is the Vue 3 technique documented anywhere?

Comment: I believe it's not documented anywhere. There's just something about global code mentioned in the [documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/configure/overview#configure-story-rendering). I think I figured out the solution by looking at their [source code](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/app/vue3/src/client).

Comment: hats off to you sir. i might go ahead and submit PR on their GitHub to add this little snippet if you don't mind?

Answer (score 5):

You can just use these lines in `preview.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.component('router-link', Vue.component('RouterLink'));

export const decorators = [(story) => ({
    components: {story},
    template: '<story />',
    router: new VueRouter()
})];
```

My vue-router problem is solved by this

Answer (score 1):

**Storybook 7 / Vue 3**

The API has changed a bit since the top answer for anyone still looking.

```
import { setup } from '@storybook/vue3'

setup((app) => {
    app.component(componentName, componentReference);
})
```